# how to get the incoming SMS in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcast

i want to print the toast message when the sms send by another device. I wrote the code. but it is not working. please any one help me out.
android version: 4.0.4
MainActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("some_string-to_call_receiver");
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent("some_string-to_call_receiver"));

    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sms" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
```

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</manifest>
```

smsreceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver   extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String SERVER_SUCCESS_CODE = "";

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String[] split_one = message.split(":");
                    String  ss = split_one[1].substring(0, 4);
                    if(ss.length()==4)
                    {
                        SERVER_SUCCESS_CODE=ss;
                    }

                    /*Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum
                            + "; message: " + message);
*/
                    // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "
                        + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }
}
```

how i get the incoming sms and toast printing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read and display incoming message text android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306150/read-and-display-incoming-message-text-android)

Comment: Check this -

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11306684/1479511

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Let us know, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Narendra i am not geting any error...my app not geting incoming message (once check my code)

Comment: If you're not getting messages then it's not mistake of the code

Comment: then wt is the problem @anushal? any problem with version?

Comment: If message is coming on your device then look at my answer and my name is anshul not anushal

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to read SMS, download the raw file from gits [Android SMS Receive Listener](https://gist.github.com/chathudan/127b7b3715687328d95e)
Implement `SMSReceivedListner` and add it `SMSReceiver.addSMSListner(this);`

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @@author Chathura Wijesinghe <cdanasiri@gmail.com> 
 * 
 * <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 */
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED         = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static ArrayList<SMSReceivedListner> smsListner = new ArrayList<SMSReceivedListner>();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (action.equals(SMSReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        final boolean smsValid = extras != null;

        if (smsValid) {
            //Create SMSMessages from PDUs in the Bundle
            final Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            //Assemble
            final ArrayList<Long> vibrations = new ArrayList<Long>();

            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                for (SMSReceivedListner smsReceivedListner : smsListner )
                    smsReceivedListner.message(message);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void addSMSListner(SMSReceivedListner listner){
    smsListner.add(listner);
}

public static void removeSMSListner(SMSReceivedListner listner){
    smsListner.remove(listner);
}

public interface SMSReceivedListner{
    public void message(SmsMessage message);
}}
```